# Sharing Localstorage token amongst multiple javascript apps on same domain but different subdomains

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Am trying to implement a single sign in amongst different applications hosted on the same domain but on different subdomains

that is the main app is hosted on mydomain.com and i want to share the token with apps hosted on app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com

Now by default i usually set my token in localstorage via

```
       window.localStorage.setItem("access-token", value);
```

and retrieve it via

```
       window.localStorage.getItem("access-token");
```

But now with the apps hosted on the main domain but on subdomains they fail to access the same localstorage values

How do i overcome this and if there are better methods on this apart from localstorage to store the jwt token

Answer (score 0):

This is browser storage security Issue, Browser does not allow it. LocalStorage cannot be shared across subdomains. These come under [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

You can do it with some `IFrame` trick. For more Please check out the link [here](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/)

**Edit - 1**

There is another approach to store the `access-token`, you can use `cookies` or `session` storage. These work across subdomains. It is advisable to use `cookie` or `session` for managing tokens, etc.